# Почему в PHP 5.3 empty() возвращает true для непустой строки?

Tags: php

Есть класс:

```
class VideoModel extends BaseModel
{
    ...
    protected $youtubeId;

    protected function setYouTubeId($value)
    {
        if (!empty($value)) {
            $this->setUploadedAt(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            $this->youtubeId = $value;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

class BaseModel
{
    ...
    public function __get($field)
    {
        // check if getter exists
        $getterName = 'get'.ucfirst($field);
        if (method_exists($this, $getterName)) {
            return $this->$getterName();
        }
        if (isset($this->$field)) {
            return $this->$field;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Этот код работает не так, как ожидается:

```
>> var_dump($webinar->youtubeId);
string 'rzCGzjbyQjc' (length=11)
>> var_dump(empty($webinar->youtubeId));
boolean true
```

Comment: `(isset($this->$field))` в коде вижу `isset` а где вы проверяете `empty` почему?

Comment: @Naumov вторая часть кода используется в контролере, для определения какую вьюшку использовать (настоящий код выглядит так: `if (!empty($webinar->youtubeId)) {
  include '_webinarPlayer.php';
 } else {
  include '_waitForRecord.php';
 }`).

Comment: `var_dump` прям перед `if` что говорит? не в консоли xdebug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для empty это вполне объяснимое поведение. При его использовании не вызывается меджик-метод __get, а так как свойство protected - то является не доступным для функции empty - получаем true.

Вам нужно определить в классе меджик-метод __isset, который будет проверять свойство при обращении к нему конструкций isset или empty.

http://php.net/__isset

Хотя, подумав, в усомнился в том, что __isset вам поможет. Он лишь определяет существование свойства. 
Возможно, правильнее, в вашем случае, будет сохранить значение свойства в переменную и работать уже с ней:

```
$youtubeId = $webinar->youtubeId;
var_dump($youtubeId);
var_dump(empty($youtubeId));
```

Comment: Проверил, действительно __get не вызывается для empty. Я поправил Ваш ответ, на самом деле поле существует но закрыто областью видимости от доступа к нему из вне.

Comment: Спасибо, ценная правка. Я не обратил на это внимания.

Comment: `empty` сначала вызывает __isset, если __isset сказал true - то вызывает __get. Реализованы должны быть оба метода.

Comment: @Мелкий проверил, Вы совершенно правы.